# Angular 9 project on firebase hosting failed to pass https requests

Tags: angular, https, proxy, firebase-hosting

I have use a proxy on my angular project as below.

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target" : "https://<domain_name>/",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

it is perfectly worked in locally with ssl for HTTPS POST requests by executing the command of,

```
ng serve --ssl true --proxy-config proxy.conf.json
```

But after I host it to the firebase hosting, it always gives below error on every POST request.

```
Http failure during parsing for https://<app_name>.firebaseapp.com/api/<route_name>
```

Comment: Are you hosting your project with env or prod environment? You need config a proxy only on the development environment, you must call your URL directly without proxy on the production environment.

Comment: Thank you @bjdose. that was the exact mistake that I had made. Due to the use of proxy, I have created a file for URLs as `/api/.../..` way. That gave me errors on building. After I created another file with full URL addresses and replace it in the production environment. Is there any proper way to solve that? I need to work the system on both dev & prod environments.

Comment: @RavinduSachintha what is the <domain_name> that you are adding in proxy config file in local? Is it the firebase domain or something else?

Comment: @Shravan backend of the system is hosted on a GCP server. <domain_name> for that. Firebase only used for hosting.

Comment: Why are you using a proxy? You can use full path for prod and dev environment. I think you don't need a proxy actually.

Comment: @bjdose you are right. But usually to get rid of cors errors, I used to use proxy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proxy config file you are including while running the Angular app in local environment to redirect certain URL segments is a feature provided by the Angular dev server.

Since you are using firebase, firebase also provides a similar redirecting feature that can be configured in the `firebase.json` file. Since you are using firebase for deployment, I assume you already have a firebase.json file. If not, visit [Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli) official docs to install it in your local environment. Now running `firebase init` command will generate a basic firebase.json file.

Include the redirect option as shown in the example below:

**firebase.json**

```
"hosting": {
  // ... other configurations ...
  "redirects": [ {
    "source": "/api/:path*",
    "destination": "https://<gcp_domain_name>/:path",
    "type": 301
  }
}
```

Let's breakdown what we just did. The source property takes a URL segment as value for Firebase to perform redirection. `:path*` specifies that any URL segment after `/api` should captured and stored in the variable `:path`. Now in the destination property, specify the destination domain followed by `/:path` to perform the redirect. The type property specifes the **Http Response code 301** to represent the permanent redirect (in your case). You can add more than one redirection in the redirects array.

For more information on the redirection configuration in Firebase, refer [this page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#capture_url_segments_for_redirects) from Firebase official docs. In addition to redirection, you can find all options that can be configured in Firebase hosting.