# How to Redirect Angular app redirect for spring services

Tags: angular, firebase, spring-boot, firebase-hosting

I have angular app hosted on firebase
The backend spring app is somewhere else. I use proxy config, that I use in my local to redirect

firebase.json

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist/myapp",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "redirects": [ {
      "source": "/server/:path*",
      "destination": "http://publicIP:firewallport/:path",
      "type": 301
    } ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Error:

> status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "https://****.web.app/server/api/v1/courses", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure during parsing for https://****.web.app/server/api/v1/courses"

How can I debug what the redirect problem is ?

The solution in [Angular 9 project on firebase hosting failed to pass https requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60462011/angular-9-project-on-firebase-hosting-failed-to-pass-https-requests)
didnt work. I do have auth0 too

Postman working with public ip and port forwarding

[image]

Comment: Your host name is not valid (starting with dot): `.web.app`

Comment: Please ignore that...I removed the firebase app name - it is https://some-50bd4.web.app/server/api/v1/courses"

Comment: OK, then next step should be to verify that you can make a successful request to the Spring backend using Postman. BR

Comment: Postman is working with public IP and port forwarding setup on my router. So app is running on port x, and router configured to map from y to x and public IP and y are used in firebase redirect destination

Comment: The backend tomcat is running on http, and firebase makes the frontend secure - https. Do I need to make my spring app also https?

Comment: Yes. And I'm a little uneasy about this redirect in your config. Does it perform an actual redirect? If yes, that may cause trouble. I'm used to having proxy setting in package.json, but I'm more used to React.

Comment: proxy config.json is ok with local application (works for me too)...but firebase will also do the same , but wont use proxy config, but firebase.json

Comment: any help if I need to use Cloud Run?

Comment: You may not be able to do it, unless your backend is deployed as container in firebase